# IObjectInspector and ClassExtensions

Tags: arcobjects, classextensions

I have a little bit of dilema here.

I have a hierachical collection of classExtensions that I very much would like to keep them as they are now:

1. Timestamper (master concrete class Extension)
   1.1) BaseCadastralExtension (derives from Timestamper)
2. Derived classes (from BaseCadastralExtension)

But I want to implement custom IObjectInspectors for each of the derived classes. I can't keep them deriving from BaseCadastralExtensions, because the IObjectInspector needs to derive from UserControl (am I right?). So, I cannot do this with multiple inheritance :P

Is it possible to implement an IObjectInspector without trashing the class structure? Or do I need to rewrite? I wonder that composition in this matter (baseCadastralExtension to have a "funcionalities" member to take care of all the events, etc) and implement for each a custom IObjectInspector would do better?

I'm not sure if I'm being clear, but I would like suggestions from you expert ESRI devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really figured this one out.

What I did was to compose the class extension with a IObjectInspector. In the init method, I would create it accordingly, like this:

My methods for object inspector just call the ones in _CustomObjectInspector

```
public class CustomExtension:BaseExtension,IObjectInspector
{
    // COM registration, etc for brevity

    protected IObjectInspector _CustomObjectInspector;

    public override Init(IClassHelper helper,IPropertySet properties)
    {
        // init our properties
        _CustomObjectInspector = new ConcreteObjectInspector();
    }

    #region IObjectInspector Members

    public void Clear()
    {
        _CustomObjectInspector.Clear();
    }

    public void Copy(IRow srcRow)
    {
        _CustomObjectInspector.Copy(srcRow);
    }

    public int HWND
    {
        get { return _CustomObjectInspector.HWND; }
    }

    public void Inspect(IEnumRow objects, IEditor Editor)
    {
        _CustomObjectInspector.Inspect(objects, Editor);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Did you consider using containment instead of inheritance?  What if the classextension contained a list of sub-extensions, then when certain events fire you would loop through the list of contained sub-extensions.  I've done this with editor extensions and found it to be effective.  Haven't tried with classextensions though it seems like it would work there too.

Comment: Hello Kirk, the suggestion is good. It would work! This one reached my purposes too. As the GOF says, inheritance is too restrictive, composition is always a better way!